# Gridview break Literal field into multi line

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with this field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">      
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Literal ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />   
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If the title is too long it completely breaks the gridview.
How can I:

1. Make the width of this column fixed.
2. If the content is too long, break it into multi lines.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the ItemStyle-Width

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"></asp:TemplateField>
```

you may need to use styling to wrap as well.

Comment: what is "styling to wrap"?
Modifying only ItemStyle-Width doesn't work.

Comment: I added the wrapping to the definition as well. did the width affect anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

Using the server control properties:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" 
                   ItemStyle-Width="300px"
                   HeaderStyle-Wrap="true"
                   ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Literal ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />   
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

These server control properties generate inline css styles. Personally, I would create appropriate css classes in your stylesheet and assign to the HeaderStyle-CssClass and ItemStyle-CssClass properties.